# Invalid ENTRYPOINT error occurs while deploying example on google cloud run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I was trying to deploy this example(from tutorial) on gogole cloud run:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudBuild/gcbapp-dockerfile-example

But It shows  `Invalid ENTRYPOINT. [name: "XXX" error: "Command \"/helloworld.sh\": invalid mode \"-rw-r--r--\" for /helloworld.sh"`

I cannot deploy the example on cloud run.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct: the file `helloworld.sh` does not have execute permissions. There are a few ways of resolving this issue:

- You can change the permissions of the file *before* building the image by running `chmod 755 helloworld.sh` on your host before running `docker build`.
- You can add logic to the Dockerfile to ensure the file has correct permissions in the container:

  ```
  FROM alpine
  COPY helloworld.sh /
  RUN chmod 755 /helloworld.sh
  CMD ["/helloworld.sh"]
  ```
- You can modify the `CMD` in the `Dockerfile` so that the file
  permissions are no longer important:

  ```
  FROM alpine
  COPY helloworld.sh /
  CMD ["sh", "/helloworld.sh"]
  ```

Any of the above solutions will allow the container to run correctly.